# How can we get time statistics about our printing in windows?

Tags: windows, printing

I am trying to implement a project which will have printing option. When a user wants to print a pdf or doc he will be able to print it. So that I want to know timings about printing times. Can you please tell me how to get timing statistics for that in Windows with a code ? 
For example I want to have this statistics : 
For 5 pages : 2 sc 
For 4 pages : 1 sc etc...

Thank you all in advance

Comment: This will depend on the printer, and therefore on whether the printer driver provides this information. You would have to build a library for each printer,  I think this maybe quite difficult.  You could just Guess!!